# Automatic calculation of line orientations in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I was able to see the types of cables ("* TYPE *" in my data table) entered manually and the length of these cables (automatically calculated using the "* Slength *" function with the name LONG in the field calculator). this whole info on the same label

```
("*TYPE||'\n'||LONG||'m'*").
```

[image]

It is now impossible to make visible the orientation of the cables (Shape of line type) in gradians (between 0 and 400), with the origin reference in the Eastern direction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get line angle you can use field calculator depending what exactly you need:
 - line_interpolate_angle(geometry,distance)
 - angle_at_vertex(geometry,vertex)

For more details check help in field calculator: [image]

Result is in degrees (north origin), to convert it in grads you need to multiply by (400/360).
So field calculator expression would be something like: `line_interpolate_angle($geometry,0) * (400 / 360)`.

Since you need angle originating from east you will need to add 90°: `(line_interpolate_angle($geometry,0)+90 )* (400 / 360)` and substract 400 for features that have value above 400g.

Comment: I'll have to do some ajusts but it was really helpfull. Thx